# Regular expressions in expect and shell script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, expect

Friends , im trying to automate a routing using expect , basically its a debug plugin in a special equipment that i need to log some data , to access this debug plugin my company needs to give me a responsekey based on a challengekey , its a lot of hosts and i need to deliver this by friday , what i've done so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

match_max 10000


set f [open "cimc.txt"]
set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach host $hosts {
spawn ssh ucs-local\\marcos@10.2.8.2
expect "Password: "
send "Temp1234\r"
expect "# "
send "connect cimc $host\r"
expect "# "
send "load debug plugin\r"
expect "ResponseKey#>"
sleep 2
set buffer $expect_out(buffer)
set fid [open output.txt w]
puts $fid $buffer
close $fid
sleep 10
spawn ./find-chag.sh
sleep 2
set b [open "key.txt"]
set challenge [read $b]
close $b
spawn ./find-rep.sh $challenge
sleep 3
set c [open "rep.txt"]
set response [read $c]
close $c
puts Response-IS
send "\r"
expect "ResponseKey#> "
send "$response"

}

$ cat find-chag.sh
cat output.txt | awk 'match($0,"ChallengeKey"){print substr($0,RSTART+15,38)}' > key.txt

$ cat find-rep.sh
curl bla-blabla.com/CIMC-key/generate?key=$1 | grep ResponseAuth | awk 'match($0,"</td><td>"){print substr($0,RSTART+9,35)}' > rep.txt
```

i dont know how to work with regexp on expect so i put the buffer output to a file and used bash script , the problem is that after i run the scripts with spawn looks like my ssh session is lost , does anyone have any tips? should i use something else instead of spawn to invoke my scripts?

Answer (score 2):

```
expect -re "my tcl compatible regular expression goes here"
```

Should allow you to use regular expressions.

Comment: For a definition of what is a tcl compatible regexp do `man re_syntax` of google `man re_syntax`.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to process strings instead of expecting something there is the `regexp` and `regsub` commands: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regexp.htm, http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regsub.htm